# Trying to sync the ropsten testnet to local server using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten, testnets

I tried syncing the ropsten ethereum testnet to my local server using the following script:

```
nohup geth --testnet --bootnodes "enode://8c5131f577ee602ccaad5e5f600011c024d43d33e6af6f8a89ed26cbfadd7efe903a8e426dde4071b857e0838a2efa29ae3b268f8b55acd59e72d4a919673cbc@13.251.47.174:30303,enode://798b8eba7b65cdd71bb061a6b18a1f7d16612d54e1aa542d8dc5c3573322b5dd7496c1eea100dbb84f8495d89f3d5ddb4142b0006a73cd32daa2f643bd5d1c76@175.24.29.183:30311,enode://9a4be35fec78cf91e7e959029ae3f5d3d3e86446186eb14f181c8f3b9917f57839ef98d4ba53cf06eb4fea696ecc14796b34d96db4f4294864edfcab27dd9956@31.220.51.107:30303,enode://2763ab6d19d6e7ce7a953ba95c9a87fe6ae5eac3434bf216282f53142d89cb5451faa701311d7de1d79cc8ecbd57f1781156e26f5722aee835547aeab870e385@52.237.88.221:30303,enode://81488a6c0b62aa14a1172d607893b6317e4f2565ca2bd73c7c0b8bfd55842af6b7972218728d1f352b3fddc61d0dccbf92e81d2bbfdc375db44ae44ee332d4db@88.198.59.75:30303,enode://3d55f613d74e90f5b8a4154d20d8a7260a973751c1402bf52adde2b08b72a9e0327a522bf187765f2d6e2a3b893dfe7aa41b204bce5f793bd9470f24fa3aafc6@178.128.241.175:30333,enode://688b37bfa38f196ccc05f74860230e4e4610cf905268448e9aa9f6dd69e3c98c64384bc329b3b753bc392f37440d1c43e208a2d0ba95a57105808babadc41a72@106.54.141.150:20182,enode://10edf84fc4daa4f7b827055d2dd64598249a31063437dddc8cffee178da2072c2d054e1cb56e96f67374f7e82a33e1f7a5ddd21363bc790f4232bb53df107e42@62.171.159.130:28657,enode://afcd20e2191dcff50f0a94e6c7abb005b2a3386bc674373a9bdcd1ca877d4a4ddbbf53b57c25081912d00d952e5ce205c27b230d860f5af1d865e2a84c117ec0@18.136.1.121:30303,enode://6ded1fed700585b38880ce0404569ef206de9a8a9f64ca98fbecc54c46dfef6a440e369a47799860291e94043f4b1357237dbc6ef0645fcf958c92aa625884c4@93.189.45.186:30303" --etherbase '0xa879118f75E671198DCD0113E6f79266fFE81B1b' --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,personal,miner,web3" --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --ipcdisable --port 2321 --cache=4096 --rpcport 52341 --mine --rpccorsdomain "*" --allow-insecure-unlock --syncmode=full &
```

It starts downloading the blocks and when it gets downloaded the blocks that are being downloaded are ahead of the current blocks available in the ropsten testnet : https://ropsten.etherscan.io/

Any idea how to sync my local server with that of ropsten testnet ?

Comment: Hi! Can you explain what you mean by the downloaded blocks being ahead of the current blocks? What are you seeing, and where?

Comment: In the logs for my geth script, it shows the block number which gets downloaded. that block number is ahead for example: if the last block number in ropsten is 10021734, the block number downloaded in my server is like 10028032.